# What is the difference between standard identifiers and predefined functions in C?

Tags: c, function, printf

I'm starting out on C and I've come across references to ***standard identifiers*** such as `printf` and `scanf`.

What is the ***difference between these and predefined functions*** that the book later describes such as `sqrt`?

I'm just trying to conceptualise (sic - I'm a brit lol) for my developing knowledge.

Surely `printf()` is a function call? It accepts an argument, doesn't it?

Is the difference based on whether they can be altered if I choose, or where they are derived from?

thanks,

(The book I'm referring to is *'Problem solving and Program Design in C'*)

Comment: Neither of those are formal names or concepts in standard C. They are all *standard library functions*, so `printf` isn't, in essence, any different from `sqrt`.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. Thank you for clarifying before I go down some dev/null rabbit hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of these terms ("*standard identifiers*", "*predefined functions*") appear in the [ISO C11 standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html).

[C11 6.4.1](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.1) describes *keywords*, such as `long`, `for`, and `return`.

[C11 6.4.2](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.2) describes *identifiers* as

> An identifier is a sequence of nondigit characters (including the underscore _, the lowercase and uppercase Latin letters, and other characters) and digits, which designates one or more entities as described in [6.2.1](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.1). Lowercase and uppercase letters are distinct. There is no specific limit on the maximum length of an identifier.

> When preprocessing tokens are converted to tokens during translation phase 7, if a preprocessing token could be converted to either a keyword or an identifier, it is converted to a keyword.

[C11 7.1.2](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.2) describes *standard headers* and *library functions*.

[C11 7.1.3](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) describes *reserved identifiers* as

> Each header declares or defines all identifiers listed in its associated subclause, and optionally declares or defines identifiers listed in its associated future library directions subclause and identifiers which are always reserved either for any use or for use as file scope identifiers.

> - All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.
> - All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.
> - Each macro name in any of the following subclauses (including the future library directions) is reserved for use as specified if any of its associated headers is included; unless explicitly stated otherwise (see [7.1.4](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4)).
> - All identifiers with external linkage in any of the following subclauses (including the future library directions) and errno are always reserved for use as identifiers with external linkage.
> - Each identifier with file scope listed in any of the following subclauses (including the future library directions) is reserved for use as a macro name and as an identifier with file scope in the same name space if any of its associated headers is included.

> No other identifiers are reserved. If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by [7.1.4](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4)), or defines a reserved identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined.

> If the program removes (with #undef) any macro definition of an identifier in the first group listed above, the behavior is undefined.

Additionally, [C11 7.31](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.31) describes *future library directions*, which includes descriptions of certain *reserved identifier* patterns.

TL;DR: `printf`, `scanf` and `sqrt` are all *reserved identifiers* for *library functions*.

Comment: `printf`, `scanf` and `sqrt` are all *reserved identifiers for **standard** library functions*.

Comment: The newer C Standard also defines *Predefined macro names* (6.10.9), *predefined constants* (6.4.4.5) `false`, `true` and `nullptr`, *predefined identifiers* such as `__func__` (6.4.2.2), and refers to the *predefined streams* `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`...

Comment: Thank you for such comprehensive answers! Teaches me to be more aware of my source